# Как найти угол между 2 точками в 3-х мерном пространстве?

Tags: java, математика

[image: картинка, с условием (сложно описать словами)]У меня есть 2 точки, камера, и точка полигона. Мне надо найти горизонтальный и вертикальный угол между ними. Надо что бы ответ был в диапазоне от -180 до 180

Точка - это объект класса Point3D (x,y,z)

Я пробовал это:

```
public static double calculateHorizontalAngle(Point3D camera, Point3D point3D) {
    int distX = (int) (camera.x-point3D.x);
    int distZ = (int) (camera.z-point3D.z);
    double distance = Math.sqrt(distX*distX+distZ*distZ);
    double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(distZ/distance));
    if (distX>0) angle=-angle+90;
    else if (distX<0) angle-=90;
    return angle;
}
```

Но смог вычислить угол только по горизонтали, а как мне вычислить вертикаль?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Нет, в пространстве нельзя получить угол между векторами в диапазоне -Pi..Pi (без выделенного третьего "опорного" направления). Однако у вас, похоже, даже и  двух векторов нет, только один. Для чего это будет дальше использоваться? Обычно достаточно компонентов вектора.

Comment: Мне это надо для определения координаты точки на экране относительно позиции и угла камеры (у камеры есть свой угол поворота)

Comment: ОК, думаю, что достаточно вектора направления.

Comment: то как можно определить вертикальный угол?

Comment: А, в этой задаче есть векторы, это разница координат (p.x-c.x;p.y-c.y;p.z-c.z)

Comment: вертикальный угол - atan(dz/(sqrt(dx^2+dy^2))), но для позиции точки на экране угол не обязательно применять

Comment: я просто что-бы определить точку на экране, вычисляю угол между камерой и точкой, и относительно центра экрана устанавливаю точку на этот угол

Comment: Между точками не бывает углов. Углы бывают между векторами. Для начала определите какие же у вас вектора.

Comment: вектора в моём случае - это разница координат точек, а модулем этих точек будет расстояние между точками

Comment: Раз такая дискуссия развернулась, нарисуйте, пожалуйста, картинку, на которой отмечены позиции камеры, точки полигона, а также вертикальный и горизонтальный углы.

Comment: Разница координат это **один** вектор. Где второй? А уж что вы называете «модулем точек» пока загадка…

Comment: какой 1, 1 вектор - это дистанция от камеры к точке, а 2 вектор - это направление камеры

Answer (score 0):

Если вы правильно вычислили один угол, то второй будет

```
    int distY = (int) (camera.y-point3D.y);
    int distZ = (int) (camera.z-point3D.z);
    double distanceY = Math.sqrt(distY*distY+distZ*distZ);
    double angleY = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(distZ/distanceY));
```